# mySQL generating rows based on a recurring date

Tags: mysql, date, recurrence

I have a mySQL table which contains events, details on the event, the event date and a recurring value - which is how often the event recurs in days.

e.g. Date: 2012-12-03, Recurrance: 7 - it will recurr every 7 days.

I am now looking to search on this by date and would like the row to be returned if the search was for 2012-12-03, 2012-12-10, 2012-12-17, 2012-12-24...+7 days.

Currently, the search is for a specific day:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    title, 
    venue, 
    date_format(datetime, '%I:%i%p') AS time 
from 
    bt_db_eventcal 
WHERE 
    DATE(datetime) = '" . $date . "'
```

Can anyone help expand this to return rows based on the recurrance?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its a simple math really. you subtract the saved date from the search date and mod the value by the recurrence. if the value is 0 then it is good.

Comment: Excellent - thanks.

The modified query is
`SELECT id, title, venue, date_format(datetime, '%I:%i%p') AS time from bt_db_eventcal WHERE DATEDIFF(DATE(datetime),'2012-12-10' % recurring=0 AND '2012-12-10'<=recur_until`

Forgot to mention there was a "recur_until" field too